# How to access Active Directory Organization Info in .Net Core 2.1 Controller

Tags: c#, active-directory, user-roles, authorize-attribute, .net-core-2.1

I have an internal web application written in C# using .NET Core 2.1. I want to get user's Department name from Active Directory (AD), which is assigned under the Organization tab in user's AD properties. Is it possible to do so?

In current application, I am able to authorize user access by simply adding a controller attribute based their AD group assignment like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "MyApp Users, MyApp Admins")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    .....
}
```

and am able to get the current AD Username through @User.Identity.Name on my razor page, which is available under System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal

I am not too familiar with AD, and @User.Identity don't have additional info I need. Any suggestion on how I can get those additional AD info? Thx!

Comment: Not much luck in finding answers to what I need. The workaround I will end up doing is to create a SQL Job to query against AD's info via LDAP.